# Need to convert oracle function into c# code

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have one function in oracle i need to convert it into c# code
please help or tell me any links to do it.

```
create or replace
FUNCTION             "GETSEPARATEDSTRING"
(  pString        IN VARCHAR2
   ,pSeparator     IN VARCHAR2
   ,pReturnNumber  IN PLS_INTEGER
)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
 l_SearchString_FinPos           PLS_INTEGER :=0;
 l_SearchString_StartPos         PLS_INTEGER :=0;
 l_SearchString_Length           PLS_INTEGER :=0;
 l_SearchString_CurrentPos       PLS_INTEGER :=0;
 l_Return                        VARCHAR2(4000);

BEGIN
  -- expecting values as String Seperator String Seperator
  -- so if pReturnNumber = 2 then where are
  -- looking for seperators 2 and 1. If there is no seperator
  -- at the end of the string it is added before comparison,
  -- Will return a null if:
  --  The length of pString is > 4000
  --  The pSeparator has not been specified
  --  The pReturnNumber IS <= 0
  --  The pReturnNumber IS greater than the number of pSeparator + 1 and therefore we can't pick up a string
  --  There was an empty string at the position requested
  -- Strings are returned without pSeparator

  IF     LENGTH( pString || pSeparator ) <= 4000
  AND pSeparator                       IS NOT NULL
  AND pReturnNumber                  >  0
  THEN
     l_SearchString_FinPos        := pReturnNumber;

     l_SearchString_StartPos      := pReturnNumber - 1;

     -- Concat a seperator at the end of the string so at least we

     -- know there is one

     IF INSTR( pString, pSeparator, -1, 1) != ( LENGTH( RTRIM( pString )) - LENGTH( pSeparator ) + 1 )

     THEN

       -- There isn't one at the end so add it

       l_Return                     := pString || pSeparator;

       --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Did not find seperator - ADDING');

     ELSE

       l_Return                     := pString;

       --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('FOUND seperator');

     END IF;

     -- Set the start position of where we will check to the

     -- the last position we found a pSeparator value.

     l_SearchString_CurrentPos    := l_SearchString_FinPos;

     -- Search for the next pSeparator position

     l_SearchString_FinPos        := INSTR( l_Return, pSeparator, 1, l_SearchString_CurrentPos );

     IF l_SearchString_FinPos != 0

     THEN

       IF l_SearchString_StartPos != 0

       THEN

         l_SearchString_CurrentPos  := l_SearchString_StartPos;

         l_SearchString_StartPos    := INSTR( l_Return, pSeparator, 1, l_SearchString_CurrentPos ) + 1;

       ELSE

         -- If we are looking for the first value then StartPos will = 0

         -- and cause INSTR to fail

         l_SearchString_CurrentPos := 1;

       END IF;

       l_SearchString_Length      := l_SearchString_FinPos - l_SearchString_StartPos;

       l_Return                   := RTRIM( SUBSTR( l_Return, l_SearchString_StartPos, l_SearchString_Length ), pSeparator );

     ELSE

       l_Return := NULL;

     END IF;

   END IF;

   RETURN l_Return;

EXCEPTION

WHEN OTHERS

THEN

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'FUNCTION GetSeperatedString Captured Error: ' || SQLERRM );

  RETURN NULL;
END;
```

Comment: I don't know pl/sql at all, but isn't this just [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx)

Comment: Just to make it easier for anyone to solve this what is the high level purpose of this pl/sql procedure?

Comment: It would be very good for you if you provide several sample input/outputs of this function and describe what is supposed to do instead of just throwing in code and ask for help. Not every body knows or has Oracle at hand but many can write C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see why you can't convert it yourself? What is the problem? You even got a comment describing exactly what the function is doing.

Do something like this:

1. Convert the method signature and all local variables to C# ones.
2. Lookup the documentation of `INSTR` to see if uses a zero-based index as `string.IndexOf`
3. Do a straight conversion by looking at one line at a time
4. Test the function
5. Rename all variables to have C# names
6. Refactor to take advantage of C#